# Magento 1.9 Invoice Tweak

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I run a wholesale shop and I allow some of my customers credit payment, for those specific customers I want to show them a two line message in invoice. Can we do it by tweaking the files of PDF Printouts in Magento Core?

Comment: Do not change directly in core codePool, insead of override it or copy the file in local codePool

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the invoice by modifying this file : `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice(app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php)`. copy this file from core to local do not touch the core filese

For more details please read following tutorials:

1. [CUSTOMIZE MAGENTO PDF INVOICE AND PACKINGSLIP](https://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/)
2. [Magento: How To Sligtly Modify the Invoice Pdf](http://www.satollo.net/magento-how-to-sligtly-modify-the-invoice-pdf)
3. [Editing an Invoice PDF](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Editing+an+Invoice+PDF)